# Чтение символов UTF-8 из файла

Tags: c++

Есть ли функция или метод для чтения многобайтовых символов из файла? Если есть, то как использовать.

Comment: Что значит "прочитать многобайтовый символ"? Если загрузить весь файл в массив байт как есть, это "чтение" или нет?

Comment: Для работы с UTF8 полно документации и готовых библиотек. Вот исходники, которые лежат у меня на диске (не помню, откуда взял). Может пригодится... https://yadi.sk/d/qyMRD5cbCIgb2g